# extent report 5 merge different report results for different machines

Tags: java, merge, report, pipeline, extentreports

I have this pipeline that runs 20 different linux machines parallel, each machine creates a report of the suite with all the tests that passed/failed.

at the end of all the runs(the last suite that finishes) I want to merge all the reports into one, how can I do such a thing.